# How to find what table in the database is causing mysqldump to fail

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP cron script that runs daily that takes a dump of an entire database, it has been working perfectly for about a year or so, all of a sudden it stopped working and I need to find where its failing.

I am almost certain that this is caused by some entry in a particular database table, I just need to find which table and what value. Is there a way to see where the script is failing? I tried dumping the `$output` and the `$errReturn` but is getting nothing. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    /**
     *
     * DESCRIPTION: THIS SCRIPT WILL READ THE SOURCE DATABASE (FTDOS LIVE) AND COPIES IT TO A .SQL FILE
     * THIS WILL SERVE AS A DAILY BACKUP
     *
     */

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');


    # DB INSTANCE 1 - ORIGIN

    defined('DB_ORIGIN_HOST')  ? null : define('DB_ORIGIN_HOST', '************');
    defined('DB_ORIGIN_USER')  ? null : define('DB_ORIGIN_USER', '************');
    defined('DB_ORIGIN_PASS')  ? null : define('DB_ORIGIN_PASS', '************');
    defined('DB_ORIGIN_NAME')  ? null : define('DB_ORIGIN_NAME', 'database_to_backup');
    defined('DB_ORIGIN_PORT')  ? null : define('DB_ORIGIN_PORT', '3306');

    defined('DB_FILEPATH')  ? null : define('DB_FILEPATH', '/path/to/store/sql_file/');

    // GENERATE THE FILENAME
    $filename = DB_FILEPATH.'factorca_'.date('Y-m-d').'.sql';

    try {
        $command = "mysqldump -h ".DB_ORIGIN_HOST." -P ".DB_ORIGIN_PORT." -u ".DB_ORIGIN_USER." -p'".DB_ORIGIN_PASS."' ".DB_ORIGIN_NAME." > ".$filename;

        exec($command,$output, $errReturn);

        if($errReturn){
            var_dump($output);
            var_dump($errReturn); 
            echo "\n[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] ERROR! FAILED TO CREATE: $filename\n";
        }else{
            echo "\n[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] SUCCESS! CREATED $filename\n";
        }

    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: mysqldump -v for verbose output

Comment: @HassanVoyeau care to elaborate?

Comment: You said you got nothing with output and errReturn and I am saying try -v switch with mysqldump, do you still get nothing?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau So basically update the line to this:  $command = "mysqldump -v -h ".DB_ORIGIN_HOST." -P ".DB_ORIGIN_PORT." -u ".DB_ORIGIN_USER." -p'".DB_ORIGIN_PASS."' ".DB_ORIGIN_NAME." > ".$filename;  Is that the right syntax?

Comment: Yes, that should work for verbose output.

Comment: Will try it, hopefully it works. Will post result here.Thanks!

Comment: @HassanVoyeau -v did not work. Still not showing any error.

Comment: @HassanVoyeau this worked: mysqldump -alv -h ".DB_ORIGIN_HOST." -P ".DB_ORIGIN_PORT." -u ".DB_ORIGIN_USER." -p'".DB_ORIGIN_PASS."' ".DB_ORIGIN_NAME." 2> ".$filename. Thanks for your help!